# ssh Tunnel (-w) “Tunnel device open failed.” on mac os

Tags: ssh, vpn, ssh-tunneling, macos

if i do

```
macos - ssh server1 -A
server1 - sudo -HE ssh root@server2 -w 0:0
```

all work fine

tun device up success

```
ifconfig -a

#contain

tun0: flags=4240<POINTOPOINT,NOARP,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 500  (UNSPEC)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

but if i try to do it from macos (10.15.7 (19H15))

```
sudo ssh root@server2 -w 0:0               
Tunnel device open failed.
Could not request tunnel forwarding.
Welcome to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.4.0-42-generic x86_64)

with -vvv
debug1: sys_tun_open: /dev/tun0 open failed: No such file or directory
Tunnel device open failed.
Could not request tunnel forwarding.
```

it's fail(

please tell me what's wrong?

------ update -------

Now everything is sad, mac os does not contain Tun Tap software, found the tuntaposx project but it does not work, Apple "remakes" KPIs (kernel programming interfaces) https://developer.apple.com/support/kernel-extensions/

I have not found alternatives yet.

And it is not yet clear how realistic this is - if ssh relies on files, objects of tun / tap adapters

Answer (score -1):

Enable tunneling on `server2` by editing the config file `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

Set `PermitTunnel yes`

Then restart SSH daemon